# Trying to embed a native WINDOWS command line in my Tkinter/Python app

Tags: python, windows, terminal, tkinter

I've done a bit of research and I've played with different graphical kits and was wondering if there was a way to display a native windows command line in my application. So, it'd be something like the command line in Jetbrains products (I think eclipse has one too), but the goal is to have 4 of them.

I've found a piece of linux software demonstrating the core concept of what I want to do and I've attached it at the bottom. Basically, I just want four terminals, and I'm going to have the app handle specific key bindings for "ease of access" tasks. I've used the linked software before and like it, but I thought as I'm exploring python it'd be a good learning experience to write something like this for windows as well!

Thanks in advance!

Edit - Google searching "Windows Tkinter Command Line" and the likes haven't been fruitful :) I promise I googled a LOT before posting here.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if there is anything readymade for this. Basically, you will need to have a text widget and simulate the output with the `subprocess` module to directly pass user input to run system commands and append results to the same text widget. You could also consider two windows - one for text input and one for result output.

Here is a link: [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: I'll give this a shot tonight when I get home. I slept on it, and had a similar idea when I woke up this morning, but I was unaware of the subprocess module.